# Launch path is not accessible when trying to run NSTask within XCUITest testing iOS app

Tags: swift, automation, xcuitest, nstask

When I try to run my .jar file that is located in the project's resources folder I get an exception that says "Launch path is not accessible."
I have created a bridge Objective-C file so swift will have access to NSTask interface.

My code source is:

```
let bundle = Bundle.main
let path = bundle.path(forResource: "/Resources/MyJar", ofType: "jar")

let task = NSTask()
task?.standardOutput = stdout
task?.standardError = stderr
task?.arguments = ["-jar", path, args]
task?.setLaunchPath("/usr/bin/java")
task?.launch()
task?.waitUntilExit()
```

Comment: What kind of test is this? Are you testing iOS or MacOS app?

Comment: @drunkencheetah I am testing iOS app using XCUITest framework. I am trying to run a .jar file from terminal directly from my tests. So i specify the path where Java is, where the .jar file is and argument to make my .jar start.

Comment: I don't think this will work, when you run tests on iOS the test runner lives on the device/simulator and does not have direct access to the host terminal. What I use in my current project is [SBTUITestTunnelHost](https://github.com/Subito-it/SBTUITestTunnelHost) which allows me to execute shell commands on the host and send push notifications with 'xcrun simctl' for example.

Comment: Thanks alot. Ill try it out and let you know if it helped